# Execute function if buttons are clicked in an order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of images for users to click.

```
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant1" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg1717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant2" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg6717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant3" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg4717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant4" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg7717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant5" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg2717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant6" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg5717.png">
```

I want a function to execute if they are clicked in order of `contestant3` then `contestant6` then `contestant1` then `contestant2`.

What would be the appropriate way to log which of these images are clicked, and the order they are clicked in, in order to execute a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding an `onclick` event to each image, and then storing the `id`'s of the clicked images in an array.

```js
var selected = [];
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.playertile');

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onclick = function() {
    selected.push(this.getAttribute('id'));
    // If array greater than four elements, remove first
    if (selected.length > 4) {
      selected.shift();
    }
    
    // Test desired condition
    if (
      selected.length === 4 && 
      selected[0] === 'contestant3' && 
      selected[1] === 'contestant6' && 
      selected[2] === 'contestant1' && 
      selected[3] === 'contestant2'
    ) {
      console.log('success!');
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="playertile" id="contestant1" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg1717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant2" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg6717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant3" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg4717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant4" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg7717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant5" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg2717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant6" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg5717.png">
```

Comment: How would I then do an if statement so it is based on the order I require? 
`If (selected = "contestant3", "contestant6", "contestant1", "contestant2") {
    //code here
}`

Comment: @EGxo updated to show one way to do that. (You'd replace `console.log` with whatever function you want to execute.)

Answer (score 0):

Added comments in the code that should explain.

Essence: Have array that keeps the execute order list. Keep a sub-array of the current order that you match against this execute order. When sub-array is fully contained in execute order array, and they are same length, it means you can safely execute your function.

You only have to change the `executeOrder` array if you want a different order, and/or more elements in your order.

```js
// the order you want
let executeOrder = ["contestant3", "contestant6", "contestant1", "contestant2"];
// the current active order of clicks
let currentOrder = [];

$(".playertile").on('click', function() {
  let elementId = $(this).attr('id');
  currentOrder.push(elementId);
  
  // keep track if the current sub list in currentOrder is still matching up with executeOrder
  let orderMatches = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < executeOrder.length; i++) {
    // if it does not match up, reset current order
    if (currentOrder[i] != undefined && executeOrder[i] != currentOrder[i]) {
      orderMatches = false;
      
      // empty current order array to start matching from sracth
      currentOrder = [];
      // if the current pressed element, is also the start of the order you want, put it back in first place, this is for example when pressing 3, 3, 6, 1, 2
      if (elementId == executeOrder[0]) {
        currentOrder.push(elementId);
      } 
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // if whole subarray (currentOrder) matched executeOrder, and they are the same length, run your function
  if (orderMatches && executeOrder.length === currentOrder.length) {  
      currentOrder = [];
      pressedInCorrectOrder();
  }
});

function pressedInCorrectOrder() {
  console.log("Images pressed in my wanted order");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="playertile" id="contestant1" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg1717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant2" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg6717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant3" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg4717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant4" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg7717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant5" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg2717.png">
    <img class="playertile" id="contestant6" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg5717.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a list depending on how many clicks you'd consider for the order.

```
let order = [];
let orderElements = 4; //could be the length of the elements or w.e.
```

Then you'll need a function that keeps adding the elements until it reaches that length and shift values if it's greater than the length.

```
function addElement(el){
   if(order.length === orderElements) order.shift();
   order.push(el);
}
```

Then you can just have a handler that keeps adding to the order array.

```
$(document).on('click', '.playertile', function(){
    addElement($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Then you can simply compare an specific order:

```
let specificOrder = ['contestant1', 'contestant2', 'contestant3', 'contestant4'];
```

And to compare:

```
function compare(order, specificOrder){
   for(let i = 0; i < specificOrder.length; i++){
       if(order[i] !== specificOrder[i]) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

All together:

```js
let order = [];
let specificOrder = ['contestant1', 'contestant2', 'contestant3', 'contestant4'];
let orderElements = 4; //could be the length of the elements e.g specificOrder.length;

function addElement(el) {
  if (order.length === orderElements) order.shift();
  order.push(el);
}

$(document).on('click', '.playertile', function() {
  addElement($(this).attr('id'));
  if(compare(order, specificOrder)) alert('You got it!');
});

function compare(order, specificOrder) {
  for (var i = 0; i < specificOrder.length; i++) {
    if (order[i] !== specificOrder[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="playertile" id="contestant1" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg1717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant2" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg6717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant3" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg4717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant4" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg7717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant5" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg2717.png">
<img class="playertile" id="contestant6" src="http://www.zwooper.com/media/cache/avatar_size/media/products/background/bg5717.png">
```